# SwiftUI wrapping UICollectionView and use compositional layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swiftui

I've tried to implement CollectionView in SwiftUI via UIViewRepresentable and use there SwiftUI views as reusable cells but cells doesn't appear at all. It seems that wrapping collection view and using compositional layout is not possible in SwiftUI, or maybe I am missing something.

I know I can implement this CollectionView completely in UIKit and just wrap all view controller but what if i want to use SwiftUI views as cells of UICollectionView?

When I am using UICollectionViewFlowLayout() views appear correctly

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct CollectionView<Section: Hashable & CaseIterable, Item: Hashable>: UIViewRepresentable {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let layout: UICollectionViewLayout
    let sections: [Section]
    let items: [Section: [Item]]

    // MARK: - Actions
    let snapshot: (() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>)?
    let content: (_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView

    // MARK: - Init
    init(layout: UICollectionViewLayout,
         sections: [Section],
         items: [Section: [Item]],
         snapshot: (() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>)? = nil,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView) {
        self.layout = layout

        self.sections = sections
        self.items = items

        self.snapshot = snapshot
        self.content = content
    }


    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

        let itemHeightDimension = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.absolute(44)
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: itemHeightDimension)
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: itemHeightDimension)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)

        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICollectionView {

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

        collectionView.delegate = context.coordinator

        collectionView.register(HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier)

        context.coordinator.dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: context.coordinator.cellProvider)


        return collectionView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICollectionView, context: Context) {

        context.coordinator.dataSource.apply( (snapshot ?? reloadSnaphot)() , animatingDifferences: true)
    }

    func reloadSnaphot() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item> {

        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections(Array(items.keys))

        items.forEach { (section, items) in
            snapshot.appendItems(items, toSection: section)
        }

        return snapshot
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>! = nil

        // MARK: - Properties
        let parent: CollectionView

        // MARK: - Init
        init(_ parent: CollectionView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            print("Did select item at \(indexPath)")
        }


        // MARK: - Cell Provider
        func cellProvider(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? {

            print("Providing cell for \(indexPath)")
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView> else {
                fatalError("Coult not load cell!")
            }

            cell.host(parent.content(indexPath, item))
            //cell.host(rootView: parent.content(indexPath, item))
            return cell
        }
    }
}

class HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<Content: View> : UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var controller: UIHostingController<Content>?

    func host(_ view: Content, parent: UIViewController? = nil) {

        if let controller = controller {
            controller.rootView = view
            controller.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        } else {
            let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            self.controller = controller
            controller.view.backgroundColor = .clear

            layoutIfNeeded()

            parent?.addChild(controller)
            contentView.addSubview(controller.view)
            controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                controller.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
                controller.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
                controller.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
                controller.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
            ])

            if let parent = parent {
                controller.didMove(toParent: parent)
            }
            controller.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've rewritten it into UIViewControllerRepresentable and now it works ok

```
struct CollectionView<Section: Hashable & CaseIterable, Item: Hashable>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let layout: UICollectionViewLayout
    let sections: [Section]
    let items: [Section: [Item]]

    // MARK: - Actions
    let snapshot: (() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>)?
    let content: (_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView

    // MARK: - Init
    init(layout: UICollectionViewLayout,
         sections: [Section],
         items: [Section: [Item]],
         snapshot: (() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>)? = nil,
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView) {
        self.layout = layout

        self.sections = sections
        self.items = items

        self.snapshot = snapshot
        self.content = content
    }


    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CollectionViewController<Section, Item> {

        let controller = CollectionViewController<Section, Item>()

        controller.layout = self.layout

        controller.snapshotForCurrentState = {

            if let snapshot = self.snapshot {
                return snapshot()
            }

            var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()

            snapshot.appendSections(self.sections)

            self.sections.forEach { section in
                snapshot.appendItems(self.items[section]!, toSection: section)
            }

            return snapshot
        }

        controller.content = content

        controller.collectionView.delegate = context.coordinator

        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CollectionViewController<Section, Item>, context: Context) {

        uiViewController.updateUI()
    }


    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        // MARK: - Properties
        let parent: CollectionView

        // MARK: - Init
        init(_ parent: CollectionView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            print("Did select item at \(indexPath)")
        }
    }
}

struct CollectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    enum Section: CaseIterable {
        case features
        case categories
    }

    enum Item: Hashable {
        case feature(feature: Feature)
        case category(category: Category)
    }

    class Feature: Hashable{
        let id: String
        let title: String

        init(id: String, title: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.title = title
        }

        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(self.id)
        }

        static func ==(lhs: Feature, rhs: Feature) -> Bool {
            lhs.id == rhs.id
        }
    }

    class Category: Hashable {
        let id: String
        let title: String

        init(id: String, title: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.title = title
        }

        func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
            hasher.combine(self.id)
        }

        static func ==(lhs: Category, rhs: Category) -> Bool {
            lhs.id == rhs.id
        }
    }

    static let items: [Section: [Item]] = {
        return [
            .features : [
                .feature(feature: Feature(id: "1", title: "Feature 1")),
                .feature(feature: Feature(id: "2", title: "Feature 2")),
                .feature(feature: Feature(id: "3", title: "Feature 3"))
            ],
            .categories : [
                .category(category: Category(id: "1", title: "Category 1")),
                .category(category: Category(id: "2", title: "Category 2")),
                .category(category: Category(id: "3", title: "Category 3"))
            ]
        ]
    }()

    static var previews: some View {

        func generateLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {

            let itemHeightDimension = NSCollectionLayoutDimension.absolute(44)
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: itemHeightDimension)
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: itemHeightDimension)
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)

            let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)

            let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
            return layout
        }

        return CollectionView(layout: generateLayout(), sections: [.features], items: items, snapshot: {

            var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
            snapshot.appendSections(Section.allCases)

            items.forEach { (section, items) in
                snapshot.appendItems(items, toSection: section)
            }

            return snapshot

        }) { (indexPath, item) -> AnyView in

            switch item {
            case .feature(let item):
                return AnyView(Text("Feature \(item.title)"))
            case .category(let item):
                return AnyView(Text("Category \(item.title)"))
            }
        }

    }
}

class CollectionViewController<Section, Item>: UIViewController
    where Section : Hashable & CaseIterable, Item : Hashable {

    var layout: UICollectionViewLayout! = nil
    var snapshotForCurrentState: (() -> NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>)! = nil
    var content: ((_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ item: Item) -> AnyView)! = nil

    lazy var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item> = {
        let dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: cellProvider)
        return dataSource
    }()

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return collectionView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureCollectionView()
        configureDataSource()
    }
}

extension CollectionViewController {

    private func configureCollectionView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.register(HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier)
    }


    private func configureDataSource() {

        // load initial data
        let snapshot : NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item> = snapshotForCurrentState()
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }

    private func cellProvider(collectionView: UICollectionView, indexPath: IndexPath, item: Item) -> UICollectionViewCell? {

        print("Providing cell for \(indexPath)")

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView>.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HostingControllerCollectionViewCell<AnyView> else {
            fatalError("Coult not load cell!")
        }

        cell.host(content(indexPath, item))

        return cell
    }
}

extension CollectionViewController {

    func updateUI() {
        let snapshot : NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item> = snapshotForCurrentState()
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}
```